# I deleted my Application.log file

Tags: coldfusion

In the ColdFusion administrator, I deleted my application.log file thinking that it would be created again the next time I ran the job.
But it's still not there.

Q: How do I turn on the application.log file again, and what's the correct way to clear the records in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe scheduled tasks will not write to application.log. it would write to Scheduler.log.

If the statement specify's CFLOG FILE="XXX.log", then check XXX.log.

Your application.log will be created when you run your application or use cflog   log = "Application "

Answer (score 2):

Ran what job? A scheduled task? That should be a different log file. The correct way to 'clear' logs is to use the rollover button in the admin. It is the one with the multiple pages. It creates a backup. Now - there is a max # of backups (10 I think) - so if you REALLY want to store stuff forever you will need to copy them yourself.

Comment: It was logging to a file called application.log, until I deleted it of course.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out a regular scheduled task will log to scheduler.log

If you are somehow logging manually to application.log yourself can't you just recreate  application.log manually or programmatically?

Comment: I didn't think I was manually logging to application.log.  I wish I had saved it now so that I could see what was creating it.